# Select rows where ID is same but Name contains different data in more than one record

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

```
ID  Name  
---------
1    ABC         
1    123              
2    BCD         
3    CDE         
4    AAA         
4    ZZZ
```

Desired Result

```
ID  Name1      Name2 
---------------------
1    ABC        123                    
2    BCD        NULL
3    CDE        NULL 
4    AAA        ZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, min(name) as name1,
       nullif(max(name), min(name)) as name2
from t
group by id;
```

If you just want a list of all names, then use a single column for the names and use `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(name) as names
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use aggregation:

```
select id, min(name) name1, case when min(name) <> max(name) then max(name) name2
from mytable
group by id
```